# How to automatically run a command when directory updates?

Tags: centos, inotify

is these a way to watch a directory in CentOS (/opt/data for example) and every time a files gets added to that directory we have a command automatically run? I installed inotify but not sure if that is the best tool.

Can you please assist? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor directory with `inotifywait` and run a command when file is added:

```bash
inotifywait -m -e create -e moved_to --no-newline --format "%f%0" /opt/data | \
   while IFS= read -r -d '' NAME; do
       echo "Added file: '${NAME}'"
   done
```

Replace `echo "Added file: '${NAME}'"` with your command.

Options for `inotifywait`:

- `-m` — don't exit after first event occured.
- `-e create -e moved_to` — events to report. Inotify distinguishes file creation events and move events, so both are specified.
- `--no-newline` — don't print newline after file name.
- `--format "%f%0"` — print zero-terminated file name only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will something like this work?
   ` #! /bin/bash
    incoming=/opt/dir1
    outgoing=/opt/dir2
    while inotifywait -qqre modify "$incoming";do
          mv /opt/dir1/* /opt/dir2/
         /opt/McAfee/cma/bin/cmdagent -l "/opt/dir2"
        echo "Done!"
    done`

Comment: I can't figure out how to add the code here. Used `  with no luck

Comment: @Tina description of your problem is not clear for me. Do you want to monitor any changes in all files under /opt/dir1 recursively? Do you need to know names of files which are added or just handle any update? What is exact use case? You can read about events which `inotifywait` can monitor in its manual page in `EVENTS` section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just need it to handle any update, don't have the name of the files.

Comment: @Tina Then you should specify proper events to monitor, and maybe filter them. I suppose `modify` is not an event you want to handle. `mv` operation will cause unwanted `modify` events by itself.